# SharePoint Foundation 2013: Posting Documents From External system To SharePoint Library

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library, wcf, integration

**The scenario**: there is an external system (PHP Back office) ) which will post documents with their metadata to SharePoint Site (**library**), when a user in the backoffice of that system will add a document. The aim is to make those documents searchable using SP Search Capabilities.

The Actions Performed from External System:

1. ADD Documents with MetaData, which should add Document to SP Library with specific values for the columns.
2. Update Document, Update Document and Column Values in SP Library
3. Delete Document, Delete Document from SP Library
4. View Document from Backoffice, Documents will be kept in the SP repository, and the DOcument will be sent to the PHP system From the SP to be Viewed.

After All, the library will be searchable in SP, for the content of the documents and their metadata.

Please, Proprose the most suitable solution.

**Scenarios we tried:**

1. We have created a windows app just for a demo purpose, where we have add the necessary C# sharepoint dlls to add documents to spsite and library with necessay values for the columns. But, it was taking a lot of time ***20*** seconds to insert a document. When we use the same code in a web part and deploy it to SP and uploaded the same document, it took ***3*** seconds. **why**?
2. **WCF** Services, we are facing a problem because sharepoint 2013 accept only 64 bit services, and when we set the platform of the service to 64. Then, deploying it, "**BAdIMageFormatException , cannot load assembly results**". we changed the platform to "ANY CPU" the same problem. **How can we solve the problem?**

Please Advise...

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of ideas:

1) Use the Copy.asmx web service.  You can just use a regular SOAP call from your PHP application to upload the file (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/copy.copy(v=office.12).aspx for details on the web service).

2) Use some custom .NET code you call from your PHP application.  This blog post has a good example: http://aashiskhanal.com/2011/07/upload-files-to-sharepoint-document-library-from-php/